# Redefine only one standard method of PyQt4 QTableWidget to my own version without making custom QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I have some function. I want it to be instead one of standard methods of the QTableWidget and (!) I don't want to make overloaded class of QTableWidget.

I tried to do this way:

```
def my_method():
    do_something()

self.ui.tableWidget.method = my_method
```

But it does not work.
Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Please avoid phrases like "does not work". Instead, describe what actually happened and include any error messages you received.

Comment: Nothing actually happened, it does not give an error, but do nothing.